# Why is my if-elif-else statement all outputting the same value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, if-statement, opencsv

[example dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fi3G.png) I am trying to evaluate a variety of conditions for the values in the `testResp.keys_raw`, `location`, and `money` columns of my `.csv` files. Depending on those conditions, I want to set the values in my `word_value_dict[word]` to 1 (correct) or -1 (incorrect) for all the words listed for each subject.

However, every time I print the output of the values, they all print as -1, when this should not be the case. I'm seeking help to resolve this issue.

```py
    # get correct/incorrect for each word from testTrials.csv
    word_value_dict = {}
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(s + 'testTrials.csv')
        with open(s + 'testTrials.csv') as testTrials_file:
            for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
                if pd.isna( row['money'] ) or row['money'] == 'money':
                    continue
                word = row['word']
                money = float( row['money'] )
                ISI = float( row['ISI'] )
                response = row['testResp.keys_raw']
                location = float( row['location'])
                print(f"{s} : Row {row_index}: Response={response}, Location={location}, Money={money}")

                # check if the money value corresponds to a correct word
                if response == 'c' and location == -150 and money == 1:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                elif response == 'a' and location == 150 and money == 1:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                elif response == 'c' and location == -150 and money == 0.01:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word 
                elif response == 'a' and location == 150 and money == 0.01:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                elif response == 'c' and location == 0:
                    word_value_dict[word] = -1 #incorrect word
                elif response == 'a' and location == 0:
                    word_value_dict[word] = -1 #incorrect word
                elif response == 'b' and location == 0:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                else:
                    word_value_dict[word] = -1 #invalid value
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'File not found for subject: {s} - testTrials.csv')
        continue 

                if word in word_value_dict.keys():
                    correct = word_value_dict[word]
                else:
                    correct = 0

                print({correct}, file=fout, end='')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'File not found for subject: {s} - studyTrials.csv')
```

I have previously tried:

```
                if response == 'c' and location == -150 and row['money'] == 1:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                elif response == 'a' and location == 150 and row['money'] == 1:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                elif response == 'c' and location == -150 and row['money'] == 0.01:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word 
                elif response == 'a' and location == 150 and row['money'] == 0.01:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                elif response == 'c' and location == 0:
                    word_value_dict[word] = -1 #incorrect word
                elif response == 'a' and location == 0:
                    word_value_dict[word] = -1 #incorrect word
                elif response == 'b' and location == 0:
                    word_value_dict[word] = 1 #correct word
                else:
                    word_value_dict[word] = -1 #invalid value

#this just outputted all the values as -1 as well.
```

I also tried:

```
 else:
                    word_value_dict[word] = None #invalid value


#This outputted all the values as None
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual dataframe. Can you post an example df that gets this result? Maybe your response values don't match up due to capitalization or whitespace or something.

Also what's the point of `with open(s + 'testTrials.csv') as testTrials_file`? I don't see `testTrials_file` referenced anywhere and you already loaded it with `pd.read_csv` anyway.

Comment: @JacobH I have just uploaded an example dataframe, however I do want to not that it appears in the photo that there's a space before every keypress entry, but I just added that extra space for this example since the cells were autocorrecting from 'a' to a'. As for the open as testTrials_file, I rewrote a lot of that script last week and forgot to take that part out, good catch!

Comment: If your response values have quotes around them in excel then they will in python too, like `"'a'"` rather than just `"a"`. You can check that after you pull them into python with `print(response)`.

Comment: Please be careful with you code samples. The exception is repeated `except FileNotFoundError:` The first exception contains a `continue` statement which is not valid and the indentation for the condition `if word in word_value_dict.keys():` is incorrect. There is reference to `row['testResp.keys_raw']` however based on your screen-shot the column name is 'testResp.key_raw'. There are some undefined variables in the code.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been mentioned, for example in the first loop your values will be

```
{s} : Row 0: Response='a', Location=150.0, Money=1.0
```

So **'response'** is equal to "**'a'**" ("**\'a\'**") and therefore will return FALSE when compared to "**a**".

You can use 'replace' to remove the single quotes around the value when obtaining the cell value.

```
response = row['testResp.key_raw']
# change to 
response = row['testResp.key_raw'].replace("'","")
```

or
Change the criteria checks to include the single quotes

```
elif response == 'a' and location == 150 and money == 1:
# change to
elif response == "\'a\'" and location == 150 and money == 1:
```